# tensorflow axis definition starts from 0 or 1?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am quite confused by Tensorflow's reduce axis function. For example, `reduce_max()`. Suppose I have a four dimension variable `a` with a shape of `a = [x, y, z, w]` where x, y, z, and w are the length that dimension. I have a command like `b = tf.reduce_max(a, axis=(1, 3))`, in this case, what will be the shape of `b`? `b = [x, z]` or `b=[y, w]`? Basically, I am just wondering which axis is the `reduce_max()` operating on. If the axis is defined from 0, then `b = [x, z]`. Otherwise, `b = [y, w]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a tensor `a`, with shape `[x, y, z, w]`. When using a function which expects the axis parameter, the axis numbering for `a` will be `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Reducing axes 1 and 3 results in those axes "disappearing" (because you are reducing those axes), so the output will consist of original axes `[0, 2]` which means the resulting shape is `[x, z]`.